# UIView changes its Origin and Height after Orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, orientation

I am using `XCDYouTubeKit` in my app. for playing yourTube Videos.

When I select any video for playing my screen changes form `Portrait` to `Landscape` and When I close the Video it goes back to `Portrait`.

Now the issue is when I close my video The `ViewController` changes its `height and origin.`

Here is what I found:

> Frame and Bound Of UIViewController before Rotation (Portrait)

```
  My view bound: {{0, 0}, {375, 563}}
  My view frame: {{770, 0}, {375, 563}}
```

> Frame and Bound Of UIViewController after Rotation (Portrait)

```
My view bound: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
My view frame: {{770, -104}, {375, 667}}
```

I Logged these in `viewDidAppear`.

```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

    {
     NSLog(@"My view bound: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
     NSLog(@"My view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));


     }
```

I am not able find exact solution. Please assist me to solve this.

Comment: u can use this =>https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: thank @sanandiyavipul but I don't want to change my Libarary fir this issue. I am looking to resolve this.

Comment: save the origin at first in a cgpont. then on close give it origin as the cgpoint we created